# Text bounding box in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, text-object

I'm making a license plate generator template.
The idea is for the user to insert a string and for blender to render the license plate. For the string `AB 12 345` this would look like
[image]

The above was generated with the following basic setup

[image]

Now I'd like to extract and save to file the coordinates of each bounding box for each character in the license plate. When connecting the `Bounding Box` node to the output I can see the boxes are correctly found

[image]
[image]

<s>but the `Viewer Node` is empty.</s>
but the bounding boxe vertices do not show up in the spreadsheet.

How can I fix this setup?

---

Edit: Adding a `Realise Instances` node after the bounding box one populates the spreadsheet. What I'm now trying to do is to export the coordinates from there to a file in a python script

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you're asking. What does Viewer Node have to do with anything, for example? Here I'm replicating your setup: https://i.imgur.com/OzZUpy8.png You can disable either the boxes or the extruded mesh easily by unlinking them from the Join Geometry node. What is missing for you?

Comment: @Kuboå yes sorry, I used the wrong terms. I edited the question.

Comment: I see, then after you realize your instances first to make them into a mesh, your question becomes "How can I export vertex positions of my object?". A native CSV export is in the works for Geometry Nodes spreadsheet (https://developer.blender.org/D12546), but in the meantime I guess you'd have to use a Python script. You might wanna check out: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-export-an-objects-vertex-positions/1397962/17

Comment: thanks I'll look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved via this https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-export-a-fonts-vertex-positions/1416165

once you convert the text to a set of vertices, you can list them and compute a bounding box for each letter/number